# Spivak, Calculus, Ch. 23 "Infinite Series", Problem 7d: Understanding solution manual solution.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following is a (long) problem from Chapter 23, "Infinite Series", from Spivak's *Calculus*. I am stuck on item (d), and my question is about that item. I am going to show you the whole problem statement, and then I will go through the solutions to items (a), (b), and (c). If you want to see the question directly, please skip to item (d) at the very bottom.

> 7. 
>
> (a) Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of integers with $0\leq a_n\leq 9$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )$
> exists (and lies between $0$ and $1$). (This, of course, is the number
> which we usually denote by $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4...$)
>
> (b) Suppose that $0\leq x\leq 1$. Prove that there is a sequence of
> integers $\{a_n\}$ with $0\leq a_n\leq 9$ and
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left (a_n\cdot 10^{-n}\right )=x$. Hint:
> For example, $a_1=[10x]$, where $[y]$ denotes the greatest integer
> which is $\leq y$.
>
> (c) Show that if $\{a_n\}$ is repeating, i.e., is of the form
> $a_1,a_2,...,a_k, a_1, a_2,...,a_k,a_1, a_2,...$, then
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left (a_n\cdot 10^{-n}\right )$ is a
> rational number (and find it). The same result naturally holds if
> $\{a_n\}$ is eventually repeating, i.e., if the sequence $\{a_{N+k}\}$
> is repeating for some $N$.
>
> (d) Prove that if $x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left (a_n\cdot
>  10^{-n}\right )$ is rational, then $\{a_n\}$ is eventually repeating.
> (Just look at the process of finding the decimal expansion of $p/q$
> dividing $q$ into $p$ by long division).

Let me go through the solutions to (a)-(c) to prepare for item (d).

**Item (a)**

Let $\{b_n\}=\{a_n\cdot10^{-n}\}$. Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n=\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{10^2}+\frac{a_3}{10^3}+...$.

For each $n$, the largest possible value $b_n$ can have is $\frac{9}{10^n}$, and the smallest value is $0$.

Thus, $$0=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 0 \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n}=1$$

By the Boundedness Criterion (A nonnegative $\{a_n\}$ is summable $\iff$ the set of partial sums of $a_n$ is bounded), $\{b_n\}$ is summable, ie $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )$ exists.

**Item (b)**

Now, given an $x$ such that $0\leq x\leq 1$, we want to prove that there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $0\leq a_n\leq 9$, and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )=x$.

We can write such a number $x$ as a decimal as $0.n_1n_2n_3n_4...$, where $n_i$  is one of $0,1,2,...,9$.

The notation will be a bit loose below, but I think the intention will be very clear. When I write a number as $n_1n_2n_3.n_4n_5$, for example, it means it is the number $10^2n_1+10n_2+n_3+10^{-1}n_4+10^{-2}n_5$.

Then,

$$10x=n_1.n_2n_3...$$

$$[10x]=n_1=a_1$$

$$\frac{[10x]}{10}=0.n_1$$

Then,

$$10^2x=n_1n_2.n_3n_4...$$

$$[10^2x]=n_1n_2$$

$$[10^2x]-10a_1=n_2=a_2$$

$$\frac{[10^2x]-10*a_1}{10^2}=0.0n_2$$

If we go one step further we obtain

$$[10^3x]-10^2a_1-10a_2=n_3=a_3$$

and

$$\frac{[10^3x]-10^2a_1-10a_2}{10^3}=0.00n_3$$

The pattern is thus that we choose

$$a_k=[10^kx]-(10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2+...+10a_{k-1})=n_k$$

It seems clear from the above that $a_k=n_k$, an integer from $0$ to $9$. We could also show this as follows.

Let

$$a_k=[10^kx]-(10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2+...+10a_{k-1})\tag{1}$$

$$=[10^kx-(10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2+...+10a_{k-1})]$$

Then

$$0\leq 10^kx-(10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2+...+10a_{k-1}) -a_k< 1$$

$$0\leq 10^kx-(10^{k-1}a_1+10^{k-2}a_2+...+10a_{k-1}+a_k) < 1$$

Multiply by $10$

$$0\leq 10^{k+1}x-(10^{k}a_1+10^{k-1}a_2+...+10^2a_{k-1}+10a_k)=a_{k+1} < 10\tag{2}$$

I.e.

$$0\leq a_{k+1}<10$$

Which shows that each element in the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is one of $0,1,2,...9$.

Now we want to show that the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )$ formed based on our newly defined $\{a_n\}$ converges to $x$.

Divide (2) by $10^{k+1}$ to obtain

$$0\leq x-(a_1 10^{-1}+a_2 10^{-2}+...+a_{n-1} 10^{1-n}+a_n 10^{-n})<10^{-n}$$

Since this is true for all $n$, then $x$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left ( a_k\cdot10^{-k} \right )$ can be made arbitrarily close by increasing $n$.

Thus

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )=x$$

**Item (c)**

Our series is now repeating, and is thus

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )= \frac{a_1}{10}+ \frac{a_2}{10^2}+...+ \frac{a_k}{10^k}+ \frac{a_1}{10^{k+1}}+ \frac{a_2}{10^{k+2}}+...+ \frac{a_k}{10^{2k}}+...$$

$$=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_1}{10^{ik+1}}+\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_2}{10^{ik+2}}+...+\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{10^{ik+k}}$$

Now,

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{10^{ik+n}}=\frac{a_n}{10^2}\frac{1}{1-0.1^k}$$

Thus,

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )=\frac{1}{1-0.1^k}\left ( \frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{10^2}+...+\frac{a_k}{10^k} \right )$$

$$=\frac{a_110^{k-1}+a_210^{k-2}+...+a_k}{10^k-1}$$

$$=x$$

which is therefore rational.

**Item (d)**

Now we assume that $x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left ( a_n\cdot10^{-n} \right )$ is rational, and want to prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is eventually repeating.

I will now show the solution manual solution verbatim for this item.

> The number $a_n$ in part $(b)$ satisfies
>
> $$0\leq \frac{10^n p}{q}-(10^{n-1}a_1+...+10a_{n-1}+a_n)<1$$
>
> Now $10^np/q$ can be written as $k+r/q$ where $k$ is an integer and
> $0\leq r\leq q-1$. In this case $$a_{n-1}=[10r/q]\tag{3}$$
>
> Since there are at most $q$ different fractions $r/q$, there will have
> to be some $m$ and $n$ with $m>n$ and $a_{n+1}=[10r/q]=a_{m+1}$. It is
> easy to see that we will then have $a_{n+2}=a_{m+2}$, etc.

My question is basically how to understand this solution. How is (3) obtained, for example?

Comment: Fixed the notation.

Comment: Should "$k=r/q$" be "$k+r/q$"?

Comment: $k+r/q$. Fixed now.

Comment: The key is that if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $g.c.d(p,q)=1$ then the fractional parts of the elements of the sequence $x,10x,10^2x,\ldots$ take values on the set $\{0.1/q,\ldots,(q-1)/q\}$ thus there are $s,r\geq0$ such that $10^sx$ and $10^{s+r}x$ have the same fractional part.